# PHP Warning: PHP Startup: murmur: Unable to initialize module, compiled with wrong API module

Tags: php, centos, php-7.1

I'm trying to compile a custom php extension against php7 on centos 7.

When I run phpize in the extensions directory I get:

```
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20160303
Zend Module Api No:      20160303
Zend Extension Api No:   320160303
```

However when I install the module and run php I get:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: murmur: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20131226
PHP    compiled with module API=20160303
These options need to match
```

Steps I've taken to resolve the issue:

- yum remove php* -y
- rm php* from /bin, /usr/bin
- verified no other phpize or php-config exists on the system

Installed php7:

```
rpm -Uvh http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm
yum -y install yum-utils yum-config-manager --enable remi-php71
yum install -y php php-devel php-mbstring php-common php-pear php-pdo php-mysqlnd php-opcache php-intl php-bcmath php-gd php-pecl-amqp php-pecl-mailparse php-xml php-mcrypt php-imap php-ldap php-pecl-memcached php-process php-cli php-pecl-zip
```

Compiled the custom extension:

```
cd {extension dir}
phpize
./configure --enable-murmur
make
```

Why would phpize tell me the extension is being compiled against PHP Api Version 20160303 but when its being loaded by php it says the module was compiled against Api version 20131226?

Comment: I removed some hidden folders in the extensions directory and everything started playing nicely.  Issue resolved.

Comment: "make clean" should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

I had some prior compiled files in the extensions directory.  Once I cleared out the files the next compile worked flawlessly in php.